# Gradle artifacts local aar and jar files

Tags: android, gradle

To gradle pros: I have an android project with modules app and facebook, app has facebook as a dependency. Module 'facebook' contains 3 files: facebook-android-sdk-4.13.2.aar, bolts-android-1.1.2.jar and build.gradle with the following contents:

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('facebook-android-sdk-4.13.2.aar'))
artifacts.add("default", file('bolts-android-1.1.2.jar'))
```

With the specified config, the project is compiled, assembled and running without any issues, but in the source file with

`import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;`
it says 'cannot resolve symbol FacebookSdk'.

I also tried the following config:

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('facebook-android-sdk-4.13.2.aar'))
dependencies.add("default", files('bolts-android-1.1.2.jar'))
```

but in that case, there are no any classes from bolts library in the dex, and when trying to address to any of those, the ClassNotFoundException is thrown.

So, how to create a correct gradle config in my case?

Comment: have you tried cleaning/rebuilding the project?

Comment: Of course I tried.